# Reapplying for a US J1 visa after two rejections

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens, us-visa

I want to reapply for a J1 visa for my PhD after two rejections with no reason given. I have funding plus a signed bond with home government for five year compulsory service and everything. I want to give it another shot as my classes will begin soon. Can I apply from another consular station in my country as my current one has a long waiting list for appointments? I read somewhere that one has to apply from the same post or is there any flexibility in that? I could get an early interview date from the other station.

Comment: They must at least have given you some boiler-plate standard reason for refusal. It is not possible they did not give you any reason. In any case if you apply again under your circumstances, you will **almost certainly** be denied again. Is your PhD in some security sensitive discipline, or engineering/science which is applicable in developing weapons of mass destruction or espionage etc? Recently some prospective students in those areas are being denied students visas. E.g. http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2018/06/more-restrictive-us-policy-chinese-graduate-student-visas-raises-alarm

Comment: Under new screening measures implemented by the Trump administration on June 11, U.S. consular officials can restrict the duration of visas granted to Chinese citizens studying certain “sensitive” subjects to one year. Although the subjects in question have not been publicly identified, reports suggest they include fields such as advanced manufacturing, robotics, and aeronautics.

Comment: My PhD is for Political Science and I am from Pakistan.

Comment: They handed over the yellow paper with 214-b written on it but they were handing it out to everyone. They didn't give any reason despite asking.

Comment: I will advise you to forget about reapplying and look elsewhere. I can almost certainly guarantee you will not be issued a visa.`Section 214(b) of the United States Immigration and Nationality Act requires that Consular Officers must assume that every visa applicant intends to leave his or her home country and immigrate to the United States.  The applicant must convey during the interview that this presumption of immigrant intent is not true`. You're from Pakistan and likely a Muslim and the USA President is Donald Trump. You know what I mean?

Comment: I know all that. The problem is I got full funding, fee waivers and everything so it is hard to accept the refusal. In my second interview, the visa officer didn't seem much impressed about my research topic. I was wondering if that caused him to reject my case.

Comment: I also came here for school twenty years and got full funding. They almost never reject students who got full funding, only rarely. Times have changed, and with you being refused twice in a row in rapid succession, there's almost no chance of being approved. Going to another consular office or having another consular officer will not change anything because the new person will see the annotations by the previous consular and will be extremely unlikely to overturn that without you giving him some extremely compelling reason. Sorry.

Comment: Wouldn’t you normally apply for an F1 visa for a PhD?

Comment: One would but my home govt is sponsoring as well so a J1 with two-year home residency and a five year mandatory service when done with PhD. Still visa rejected twice.

Comment: You should discuss this in depth with your US university.  They may not be able to solve your situation, but they should be concerned when they're losing a student they already deemed qualified for a fully funded PhD program.  It seems this problem is partly caused by US politics---I don't have a solution but raising awareness among sympathetic faculty may be a start.